# Passando informações de um arquivo para uma matriz

Tags: c

Estou com um problema, eu quero receber um arquivo e copiar as informações desse arquivo para uma matriz alocada por mim:

Conteúdo que existe dentro do arquivo:

```
2..E.5..A......D
....1E....7B80..
F.8.A.......C.4.
AC...3.F...E.61.
.3...C.45..2..BF
.D9.5..31.A..E0.
E5A...9..0..7C..
...C6..B.E..5.2.
.9......ED0F...C
.E...8.DC..A..F7
....EB7...9.....
5....FAC......D.
.6..C7B9....F.5.
8.........D.94.2
..2..D1...C63..B
.7..8..6.BF..D..
```

E quero copia-lo para uma matriz 16 por 16 que criei, e a função que  faz isso esta aqui:

```
char** lerMatriz(char ** tabuleiro, char * arquivo, int l, int c)
{
    char** tabuleiroP;
    int i, j;
    char carac;
    FILE* p;

    p = fopen(arquivo, "r");

    for(i = 0 ; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            tabuleiroP = fgets(tabuleiro, 256, p);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i ++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", tabuleiro[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(p);
}
```

Sendo o meu `char** tabuleiro` a minha matriz 16 x 16, `char* arquivo` a minha string que contém o nome do arquivo e `int l` e `int c` o número de linhas e colunas da matriz (16 x 16).

Qual seria o problema no meu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem vários problemas com o seu código. Vou falar os que eu achei mas não posso garantir que é uma lista exaustiva.

Em primeiro lugar não basta ler 256 caracteres da entrada e jogar direto na matriz. Você está esquecendo as quebras de linha ("\n")

Em segundo lugar, `l` e `c` são sempre 16 ou podem ser outros números também? Se for sempre 16 você não precisa passar eles como parâmetro e se não for sempre 16 você deveria estar usando esses limites ao invés de 16 nos seus loops.

De qualquer forma, um nome mais descritivo seria útil. Por exemplo, `ncol` ao invés de `c`.

Daqui pra frente eu vou assumir que é sempre 16, porque assim podemos usar alocação estática, que simplifica as coisas.

Um terceiro problema é que não está claro  o que sua função faz, isso é: o que ela recebe e o que ela retorna. Qual a diferença entre tabuleiro e tabuleiroP? Poque você disse que a função retorna um `char**` mas não usa nenhum `return`?

Um quarto problema bastante importante é que você não está alocando espaço de armazenamento para a sua matriz. Simplesmente declarar um ponteiro não aloca espaço para um vetor. Além disso, `char **` não é equivalente a 'char[16][16]`. A correspondência entre vetores e ponteiros só vale pra vetores de uma dimensão (e olhe lá).

Uma maneira que funciona pra resolver esse problema é fazer sua função receber uma referência pra matriz a ser preenchida e colocar os valores lidos dentro dela. Aproveitei também pra fazer a função receber um `FILE*` ao invés de um nome de arquivo, que é algo mais genérico (por exemplo, você agora pode ler a matriz do stdin ao invés de um arquivo nomeado)

```
#define NLIN 16
#define NCOL 16

void lerMatriz(FILE *arquivo, char out[NLIN][NCOL]){
    int c;
    for(int i=0; i<NLIN; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<NCOL; j++){
            c = fgetc(arquivo);
            if(c == EOF){ /*ERRO*/ }
            out[i][j] = c;
        }
        c = fgetc(arquivo);
        if(c != '\n'){ /*ERRO*/ }
    }
}

int main(){
    FILE *entrada = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");

    char tabuleiro[NLIN][NCOL];
    letMatriz(entrada, tabuleiro);


    for(int i = 0; i < NLIN; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < NCOL; j++){
            printf("%c", tabuleiro[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(entrada);
    return 0;
}
```

A melhor maneira de tratar erros de leitura fica como exercício :)