# Como ler uma matriz de um txt

Tags: c, matriz

Precisava de imprimir uma matriz que tenho no txt no terminal.

Este é o meu txt:

```
010009070
300001000
070080000
807000000
050076000
064000510
030200000
092400000
000000023
```

O que eu já tentei:

```
int getGrid(char *filename, int lines, int columns, int **mat) {

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return mat;

}
```

```
main(){
 int **mat = malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        mat[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    }
    //fillGridRandom(&row, &col, 10);
    char *filename = "C:/SudokuX/InitTab.txt";
    getGrid(filename, N, N, mat);
}
```

Comment: Mas qual é o problema?

Comment: imprime lixo em vez do conteudo do txt

Comment: getGrid(filename, N, N, mat); o N ta declarado onde? Pode postar todo o código?

Comment: Você definiu sua função `getGrid`como retornando um `int` mas está retornando um `int **`.

Comment: Não sei quantas colunas você espera ler em cada linha, já que você não informou o valor de N, mas da maneira como você exibiu seu arquivo cada linha possui um único inteiro.

Comment: @ValmorFlores N=9

Comment: Sim, imaginei. Veja a resposta, dividi em duas LIN e COL ;)

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Fiz em um bloco único a sua proposta. Depois divida em função como desejar. Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LIN 9
#define COL 9

int main()
{

    int **mat ;
    int i, j ;

    int dado;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen ("tabela.txt", "r+");
    mat = ( int ** ) malloc (LIN * sizeof (int*)) ;
    for (i=0; i < LIN; i++)
    mat[i] = ( int * ) malloc (COL * sizeof (int)) ;
    for (i=0; i < LIN; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j < COL; j++)
        {
        dado = fgetc(fp);        
        mat[i][j] = dado ;
        }
    }

    printf("\nMatriz:\n");
    for(i=0;i<LIN;i++)
    {

       for(j=0;j<COL;j++)
       {
           if ( mat[i][j] == 10 )
           {
               printf("\n");
           }
           else
           {
               /* code */
               printf("%3d\t", mat[i][j]-48);
           }
       }
    }

    // libera a memória da matriz
    for (i=0; i < LIN; i++)
       free (mat[i]) ;
    free (mat) ;

}
```

Mas, sem malloc existem opções mais simples.
Inclusive em uma proposta ja discutida aqui:
[Passando informações de um arquivo para uma matriz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70349/passando-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-um-arquivo-para-uma-matriz)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NLIN 9
#define NCOL 9

void lerMatriz(FILE *arquivo, char out[NLIN][NCOL]){
    int c;
    for(int i=0; i<NLIN; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<NCOL; j++){
            c = fgetc(arquivo);
            if(c == EOF){ /*ERRO*/ }
            out[i][j] = c;
        }
        c = fgetc(arquivo);
        if(c != '\n'){ /*ERRO*/ }
    }
}

int main(){
    FILE *entrada = fopen("tabela.txt", "r");

    char tabuleiro[NLIN][NCOL];
    lerMatriz(entrada, tabuleiro);


    for(int i = 0; i < NLIN; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < NCOL; j++){
            printf("%c", tabuleiro[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(entrada);
    return 0;
}
```

Cópia em repositório:
https://github.com/valmorflores/matriz_c_malloc.git

Comment: Como, me parece, ele deseja uma matriz de inteiros, e não de char, aqui: `dado = fgetc(fp); ` deveria ser: `dado = fgetc(fp) - '0';`